# .net Test Project not Copying Dependency Binary Reference

Tags: c#, .net, dll, automated-tests

I have a .net test project that has a project reference to ProjectA which in turn has a binary reference to ProjectB.dll. When I run my automated test, I get the following error:

```
An exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in ProjectA.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Could not load file or assembly 'ProjectB, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

As the message points out, ProjectB.dll is missing from my test project bin folder. The reference to ProjectB.dll in ProjectA has Copy Local = True, so it exists in ProjectA's bin folder.

If I directly reference ProjectB.dll in my test project, ProjectB.dll is copied to the test project bin folder and the error is resolved. However, I don't think I should have to directly reference ProjectB.dll from my test project to get the reference to copy. Other projects that ProjectA references have their binaries copied. They are project references though.

Is there any way to get the binary reference to copy without directly referencing it in the test project?